# What does this rail-splitter-like circuit do?

Tags: bjt, virtual-ground

I'm repairing an audio amplifier for a car. It has a switching supply that generates +/- 50V rails from the ~12V battery. In the output section of the amplifier, I found this small circuit with obviously damaged components. When I found it, the base and collector of Q2 were bridged with solder in what I assume was an error made by a previous attempt at a repair by someone else.

R1 is scorched badly enough that I can't identify it, though it tests as 23.2 kohms. R2 has color bands indicating it's supposed to be 33.2 ohms, though it actually tests as 3.32 kohms. R3 appears to be labelled as 200 ohms, but the 3rd band could be a faded yellow or gold. R3 tests as open circuit. D1 used to be a 1N4735A zener but it doesn't zeen anymore and instead tests as a 5 Mohm resistor in both directions.

I'd like to replace all the parts in this circuit with known good parts, but I'm having difficultly understanding what this circuit is supposed to do so that I can select appropriate resistor values. It looks like a rail-splitter, but it has no inputs or outputs other than the two rails. The circuit doesn't produce a virtual ground, but there's also no need for one here because the battery negative terminal serves as a ground.

I've removed this circuit from the board entirely and everything seems to work fine without it, though I haven't tested the amplifier at full load.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRxqGd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What is this circuit supposed to do? What would appropriate values for R1, R2, and R3 be?

Comment: No inputs or output load shown!    D1 is likely a Zener 0.7x4 +0.x .It is just a complementary current buffer, ~<=10k , unity V gain but missing parts for emitter R’s and input C’s and heatsink must be rated for same as audio power 50% efficiency or so

Comment: Thanks @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75. I fixed the direction of D1 and replaced the symbol with a zener. As far as I can tell there are no outputs from the circuit which is why I am completely baffled. The only two traces running to this section of the board are for +50V and -50V.

Comment: what output load was it intended for. was this a DIY thingy?  It needs an Op Amp for low crossover distortion. Can't you measure the Zener voltage?

Comment: Do you have an 90V signal input swing to get full power? and high GBW feedback to get rid of crossover distortion?? then toss it and buy a class D Amp really

Comment: At this point I'm motivated to get it fixed for the learning experience and out of pure stubbornness. To answer your other questions, this is a commercial product from circa 2000 though with very low production numbers - only 100 units made, I believe. The final output stage has 3 each of 2SA1943 / 2SC5200 BJTs and I do see a full-height output when driven with a 60Hz sine wave input. And that's with this mysterious circuit totally removed from the board.

Comment: Unless you have preamp with 1:100V voltage gain, you are wasting your time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be intended to generate a constant load on the 50 V rails. Some (early) switched supplies don't regulate properly at low output current. A circuit like this could guarantee enough load to allow proper regulation. It might have been easier to add this circuit than modify the switched supplies to work properly at low output current.

What voltages do you get on the power rails with no audio and running at a decent volume? If you can disconnect the amplifier from the 50 V supplies what output voltages do they then have? Is there a voltage rating printed on the zener diode?

Comment: That seems like a good guess to me. The board is one piece so I can't easily disconnect it, but the rails sit comfortably at 50V with no load at all. It does draw about 2.3 A at 12V though, which seems suspiciously high. At least that would be high for a class D. The supply itself is controlled by a pair of SG3524. One controls a +/- 25V rail that also seems to be working fine and isn't connected to this part of the board. D1 is 1W with a 6.2 V zener voltage.